# ORDER BY child-parent hierarchy using MS SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, sql-order-by

I have a table named `Department` with 3 column: `DepartmentID`, `DepartmentName`, `ParentID`.

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f04e7/1) for details

I want to order the results by ParentID and Generation. Like this:
╔═════════╦════════════════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ ChildID ║ DepartmentName ║ Generation ║ ParentID ║
╠═════════╬════════════════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║       1 ║ Manager        ║          0 ║ NULL     ║
║       6 ║ Sales          ║          1 ║ 1        ║
║       7 ║ Fleet          ║          1 ║ 1        ║
║       4 ║ Cargo          ║          2 ║ 7        ║
║       5 ║ Transport      ║          2 ║ 7        ║
║       2 ║ IT             ║          2 ║ 6        ║
║       3 ║ Food           ║          2 ║ 6        ║
╚═════════╩════════════════╩════════════╩══════════╝

I tried different `ORDER BY`s but none worked.

My stored procedure:

```
WITH Hierarchy(ChildId, DeparmentName, Generation, ParentID)
AS
(
SELECT DepartmentID, DeparmentName, 0, ParentID
    FROM Departments AS FirtGeneration
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL 
UNION ALL
    SELECT NextGeneration.DepartmentID, NextGeneration.DeparmentName, Parent.Generation + 1, Parent.ChildId
        FROM Departments AS NextGeneration
        INNER JOIN Hierarchy AS Parent ON NextGeneration.ParentID = Parent.ChildId    
)
SELECT * FROM Hierarchy
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

I use MS SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing the *path* to the top in the hierarchical query:

```
WITH Hierarchy(ChildId, DeparmentName, Generation, ParentID, Path) AS (
      SELECT DepartmentID, DepartmentName, 0, ParentID,
             RIGHT('000' + CAST(DepartmentID as VARCHAR(MAX)), 3) as Path
      FROM Departments FirstGeneration
      WHERE ParentID IS NULL 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT NextGeneration.DepartmentID, NextGeneration.DeparmentName, Parent.Generation + 1, Parent.ChildId,
             Path + '-->' + CAST(RIGHT('000' + CAST(NextGeneration.DepartmentID as VARCHAR(MAX)), 3)
      FROM Departments NextGeneration INNER JOIN
           Hierarchy Parent
           ON NextGeneration.ParentID = Parent.ChildId    
     )
SELECT h.*
FROM Hierarchy h
ORDER BY path
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

Comment: The code doesn't run. There are some SQL syntax errors.